# Accessing shared memory from a signal handler

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, multiprocessing, deadlock, semaphore

I have this issue with using signal handlers. I have a parent process defining a shared memory. It forks two child processes which have a signal handler for signal of a certain type. Now whenever the child processes receive that particular signal their signal handler handles that signal.

Now what I need is to keep track the number of times the signal is handled by the signal handlers. I need to use that shared memory to increment the counter for the number of times the signal is handled by either of the child processes

For that I might be needing to use semaphores. But my question is whenever the signal is handled by the handler, it has to check if the shared memory is being accessed, if it is being accesses it cannot increment the counter, then it might have to block. I don't think we can block in a signal handler.

So what is the best way to achieve this. Both my child processes register the same signal handler for handing the signal of type lets say 1. So whenever that particular signal is received, both of their signal handler routine which is the same will try to increment the counter.

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can block in a signal handler, sort of. What I mean is: you can safely block for the other process to finish what it's doing. The unusual deadlock possibility is with your own process - if a  particular thread in the process has locked the mutex (or semaphore), then the kernel hijacks that thread to handle the signal, and it waits for the lock: deadlock. The thread's main stack won't release the lock until the signal handler finishes, the signal handler won't finish until the main stack releases the lock.

(That same self-deadlock problem happens is hidden in all kinds of common calls like `malloc`. That's why there's a very short list of library functions which are guaranteed to be "signal-safe".)

I see a couple ways to solve this:

- don't allow the signal handler to run from a thread that has the lock. There are at least three ways to accomplish this using `pthread_sigmask`:

  1. You can temporarily mask the signal in that thread prior to lock acquisition and unmask it after lock release. There's some cost of the extra system calls, of course, so you may want to avoid this approach if this is performance-sensitive code.
  2. You can permanently mask it in all threads and use a `sigwait` loop from some thread to handle the signal without a conventional signal handler at all. This would free you from all the worries about "signal-safe" functions and the like.
  3. You can permanently mask it in that thread and have some other thread running with a conventional signal handler, either one doing other "real" work or just a `sigsuspend` loop.
- use atomics. If this is a simple counter, you can avoid locking entirely. The signal handler never waits for the main thread. The main thread has no particular problem either - maybe a compare-and-swap loop will run an extra iteration because the signal handler ran between, but this isn't really a problem. I'm not completely sure if [C++11 atomics](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) are guaranteed to operate correctly on a shared memory region, though. You may need to look into your platform's implementation. I can't think off the top of my head of any reason they would care about other thread vs. other process using a shared memory segment, but I don't want to overpromise.